# jQuery self = this resets click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, bing-maps

I have a piece of code which is integrating Bing maps within the jQuery Mobile framework
things are working well if not for the text that is displayed within each marker

the markers are displayed in the right location, however the text seems to change to the one of the last marker generated

this is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
{
  marker_description = locations[i].description;
      marker_title = locations[i].title;
  var self = this;


  self.addMarker({'location': locations[i].lat +','+locations[i].long, 'bounds' : true })
  .click(function() {
      self.openInfoWindow({
        'title': marker_title,
        'description': marker_description
      }, this);
  });
}
```

so the problem is that when I click on each marker, the popup that opens is displaying the value of the last item of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the callbacks you define are called, your variables have changed.

You may protect them with an immediately executed closure like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   (function(i){
      var marker_description = locations[i].description; // be careful to use local variables
      var marker_title = locations[i].title;
      var self = this;
      self.addMarker({'location': locations[i].lat +','+locations[i].long, 'bounds' : true })
      .click(function() {
          self.openInfoWindow({
            'title': marker_title,
            'description': marker_description
          }, this);
      });
  })(i);
}
```

Note the `var` I added to make the variable local.